# What do I search for?

Tags: riddle

```
In the morning you brush your teeth with it. (hopefully)
You can sit on it.
At night you lay down on it.
```

No hints needed, my father told me that one ages ago and I still like it.

Comment: If the accepted answer is the "proper" one, where's the riddle? It's not just that this is easy; it's that without a single "tricky" answer, this is just a series of questions about items used in common activities.

Comment: Of course some humor is needed to finish this one. But still it has it's own charme. I never said I search for only one word / answer. And I would say it trains your brain to think differently as well which is needed for some others. I am from germany and might miss-interpret the word riddle a bit. what tag do you suggest? riddle + humor ?

Comment: The problem isn't that "riddle" is inappropriate, it's that this is failing to be a puzzle of any kind. If you asked these questions outside the context of a puzzle site, it wouldn't be considered a puzzle. It would be considered three very easy to answer (with minor cultural assumptions) questions. If you insist that it's a puzzle, the "trick" is that it isn't really a puzzle.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because there is no puzzle.

Comment: this puzzle is to find your humor

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You search for

> a toothbrush, a chair and a bed

At least that's how it went when I was a child.

Comment: I will accept that answer as soon as possible.

Comment: What's the puzzle here?

Comment: @EnvisionAndDevelop I think the puzzle is that you spend time trying to think of one thing to fulfill the requirements. It's like an anti-riddle, for children.

Comment: the puzzle is that you are searching for something else and in fact it was not a requirement to have a single word answer, or even just one. Love it or hate it, in my office we laughed out loud when I answered it.

Answer (score 9):

> A pair of **pyjamas**. In the morning you brush your teeth while you are still wearing it. You can of course sit down while wearing it. And in the night, you go to sleep with it.

Comment: I like this one the best.

Answer (score 6):

> Nylon, all three you described can be made of this?

Comment: not what I was thinking, but I like what you proposed

Answer (score 4):

> Your hand? Assuming you sit and sleep in a weird position

Answer (score 0):

The answer I believe is a

> Rock.

Cavemen brushed their teeth with it (lol I think)

You can sit on one.

And, cavemen probably laid on it to sleep :D